# RSPEC Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am stumped. I am not sure how to locate the source of my issues. Here is the error I get:

```
> bundle exec rspec spec 

ThemeMaintainer
  should have tests (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) ThemeMaintainer should have tests
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     TypeError:
       wrong argument type Class (expected Module)
     # /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.12/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:170:in `include'
     # /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.12/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:170:in `block in add_template_helper'
     # /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.12/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:170:in `module_eval'
     # /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.12/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:170:in `add_template_helper'
     # /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.12/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:95:in `block in helper'
     # /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.12/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:94:in `each'
     # /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.12/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:94:in `helper'
     # /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.12/lib/action_view/test_case.rb:93:in `include_helper_modules!'
     # /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.12/lib/action_view/test_case.rb:86:in `new'

Finished in 0.0017 seconds (files took 13.66 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/helpers/theme_maintainer_spec.rb:4 # ThemeMaintainer should have tests

Top 1 slowest examples (0.00001 seconds, 0.8% of total time):
  ThemeMaintainer should have tests
    0.00001 seconds ./spec/helpers/theme_maintainer_spec.rb:4

Randomized with seed 27022

Coverage report generated for RSpec to /Users/tj/projects/AOT/aotv2/coverage. 9272 / 22617 LOC (41.0%) covered.
/Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.12/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:170:in `include': wrong argument type Class (expected Module) (TypeError)
    from /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.12/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:170:in `block in add_template_helper'
    from /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.12/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:170:in `module_eval'
    from /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.12/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:170:in `add_template_helper'
    from /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.12/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:95:in `block in helper'
    from /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.12/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:94:in `each'
    from /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.12/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:94:in `helper'
    from /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.12/lib/action_view/test_case.rb:93:in `include_helper_modules!'
    from /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.12/lib/action_view/test_case.rb:86:in `new'
    from /Users/tj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:472:in `run'
    from /Users/tj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:111:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
    from /Users/tj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:111:in `map'
    from /Users/tj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:111:in `block in run_specs'
    from /Users/tj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:53:in `report'
    from /Users/tj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:107:in `run_specs'
    from /Users/tj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
    from /Users/tj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /Users/tj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
    from /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

and here is the spec

```
require 'spec_helper.rb'

RSpec.describe ThemeMaintainer do
  it 'should have tests'

end
```

Everytime I run `rspec spec` I get an error right away on a different spec (it is randomizing sequence of tests). Obviously? there is nothing wrong with the ThemeMaintainer spec. And each one that I get an error on I can easily pass when run by itself.

So my question is how do I find the spec that is really failing?

I have 8 dirs under specs. I run them `rspec spec/<dir>` 8 individual runs and all runs fine. Only when I run `rspec spec` for the whole app do I get the error. Stacktrace is ALWAYS the same. Error is always the same.

I could use some guidance on how to diagnose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently as was recommended in a Github issue response, `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` should not be being used (as in turn it off in RSpec.configure) and that solves the problem.

I am still not sure why having had it on for 2 years and not having any issue thus far that it now failed.

Comment: After writing this - I suspect there are a number of conditions that can cause the original problem. Mine was solely the one above. YMMV. Post what you find was your solution when you have one.

Answer (score -3):

You didn't close the block.

```
require 'spec_helper.rb'

RSpec.describe ThemeMaintainer do
  it 'should have tests' do
  end
end
```

Comment: I doubt changing a pending test to a FAKE test is the problem.